# Facebook не видет картинку в мета og:image

Tags: facebook, meta, sharing

На просторах интернета, подобных вопросов видел уже кучу, но вот чтобы хотя бы один помог то нет, на самом сайте картинка в **og:image** указана, работаєт, но фейсбук дебагер пишет следующие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Он предлагает добавить **og:image:width** и **og:image:height**, но в мета которых он же и наблюдает то чего ему не хватает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка тоже прекрасно загружается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И данная проблема только на фейсбук, на остальных платформах все работает без проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что домен который использовался для стореджа картинок имел битый ssl от lets encripty, проверить сертификат можно тут https://whatsmychaincert.com/ и детальный репорт тут https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html в браузере вы не поймёмте, что сертификат у вас настроен не правильно, так как современные браузеры умеют фиксить мелкие недочёты сертификата, но увы Фейсбук так не умеет, и при решении проблемы с сертификатом пропала и проблема с самим Фейсбуком.